# "No Current Record" error on acCmdSaveRecord when BeforeUpdate is cancelled

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` to save a record, and I'm trying to use the form's `BeforeUpdate` event to validate certain fields that I don't want to be left blank before the record is saved.

I'm a bit new to using `BeforeUpdate` so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly; here's my `BeforeUpdate` code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If IsNull(Me.[First Name]) Or IsNull(Me.LastName) Or IsNull(Me.DateOfBirth) Or IsNull(Me.CourseStartDate) Then

        MsgBox "Before the enrolment can be saved, you must provide:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
             & "- First Name" & vbCrLf _
             & "- Last Name" & vbCrLf _
             & "- Date of Birth" & vbCrLf _
             & "- Start Date" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
             & "You must also attach a course. This can be done by selecting " _
             & "the appropriate course in the Prospectus Search and clicking " _
             & "the Use Prospectus Code button." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
             & "If your course is not currently in the prospectus, you can " _
             & "add it first by clicking the Add Course button.", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation

        Cancel = True

    Else

        Me!EnrolmentID = "Enr" & Format(Me!ID, String(12 - Len("Enr"), "0"))

    End If

End Sub
```

So this basically tests to see if certain fields have been left blank, if they have been left blank then a message box is displayed showing what fields need data and then the update is cancelled. Otherwise it assigns a custom primary key and allows the record to update.

It's throwing an error when cancelling the update though stating "No Current Record" and highlighting the `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` line of code.

What do I need to do to avoid the error? I've also tried `Me.Dirty = False`, but still get the same error.

**@Johnny Bones:**

Here's a simplified test I've tried on the answer you gave me:

```vb
Public ShouldRun As Boolean
```

```vb
Private Sub Command7_Click()

    If ShouldRun = True Then

        MsgBox ShouldRun

        RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    End If

End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If IsNull(Me.Field1) Or IsNull(Me.Field2) Then

        MsgBox "This is the true"

        ShouldRun = False

    Else

        MsgBox "This is the false"

        ShouldRun = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Basically none of the `MsgBox` functions are firing and the record is being saved regardless of whether a field is being left blank or not. I tried this as a test because the `MsgBox` in my real code was not firing in the BeforeUpdate event either. Can't see why though.. if a user leaves one of the fields blank this should trigger the true part of the if statement in the BeforeUpdate event, right?

The only thing I can think of is that the BeforeUpdate event is not being triggered by `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`, despite [MSDN saying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238523%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

"if you then move to another record **or save the record**, the form's BeforeUpdate event does occur."

Not sure what the order is here... does VBA run the `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` then the BeforeUpdate event? If this is the case then the `ShouldRun` variable won't have any assignment at the first step (`RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`) because it only gets that at the second (BeforeUpdate).

Comment: In what event do you call RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord?

Comment: command button's OnClick event.

Comment: If it seems like the `Before Update` event is not firing, open the form in Design View and inspect the Properties page for the form to make sure that it says `[Event Procedure]` for the `Before Update` event. (Sometimes the VBA code exists but the link from the form to the code does not.)

Comment: It's in there. I'm just confused how people get this beforeupdate event working for them. Johnny Bones' answer seems to call a variable before it gets an assignment (and bypasses the `cancel` argument). My current code uses the `cancel` argument, but then triggers an error saying "no current record". Thought this would be straight-forward! ...good old Access! All I want is to check a few field are not blank. If any are then I want to display a user-friendly message and not save record, otherwise save the record.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a global variable like this:

```
Global ShouldRun as Bool
```

You throw that at the very top of the code page, up where you declare Options Explicit.  Then, in the If/Then/Else statement you provided above, replace the line:

```
Cancel = True
```

with

```
ShouldRun = False
```

and in the Else part add the line

```
ShouldRun = True
```

Finally, your command button's OnClick event should look more like this:

```
If ShouldRun = True then
  RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
```

By doing this, it will never even try to save the record if it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't think this is working. I've added a simplified version of the code to my question. Also I've changed `Global ShouldRun as Bool` to `Public ShouldRun as Boolean` as the former wasn't recognised by vb.

Comment: The problem here is that `ShouldRun` would be set in the `BeforeUpdate` event procedure which is fired when trying to save the record (so AFTER you check its value).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but have you tried to use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`
instead?

Because for me it's firing the `Before Update` event well, when `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` wasn't!

But after cancelling the event you may get an execution error '2759', because the record can not be save anymore. 
So you can handle it this way :

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
On Error GoTo Command7_Click_Error

     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Command7_Click_Exit:
     Exit Sub

Command7_Click_Error:
     If Err.Number=2759 Then
         'ignore the error
     Else
         MsgBox Err.Description
     End If    
     Resume Exit_Here
End Sub
```

If you are using `Me.Dirty = False` instead, you can handle the error '2101'.

Hope it helps

Comment: and when using `Me.Dirty = False` ?

Comment: Don't know, I think 3021 was just during debugging, otherwise it's 2501. It's totally ok for me to handle/ignore that specific error, as long as Access really prevents the record from being saved.  :-)