# Bypass BeforeUpdate Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to bypass the BeforeUpdate event? I've got some code in my BeforeUpdate event that runs when an attempt to save the record is made, however on the same form I have a subform that requires the user to select a record in that subform. As this changes the focus of the current record it triggers my BeforeUpdate code, which I don't want it to do.

Is there a way of bypassing the form's BeforeUpdate event when the user clicks on a record in a form's subform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Is there a way of bypassing the form's BeforeUpdate event when the user clicks on a record in a form's subform?"*

When you switch focus to a subform with an unsaved record in the main form, Access will automatically attempt to save the "dirty" main form record.

That behavior is built into Access and you can't prevent it.

I think you should use a different approach.  Currently (based on the comments discussion) you have a command button to save the main form record.  However if certain controls contain Null, you abort the save from the form's *BeforeUpdate* event.

From my point of view, the user should not even be able to click the command button when any of those controls contain Null.  (Why let them click a button and then inform them the action is invalid?)  So I suggest you only enable the command button when all those controls contain non-Null values.

Consider a command button named *cmdSave* and 3 text boxes: *txtOne*, *txtTwo*, and *txtThree*.  Create a procedure, *SetButtonAvailability*, and call that procedure in the *AfterUpdate* events of all 3 text boxes.

```vb
Private Sub SetButtonAvailability
    If IsNull(Me.txtOne) Or IsNull(Me.txtTwo) Or IsNull(Me.txtThree) Then
        Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.cmdSave.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Also in the form's *OnCurrent* event, you would do `Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False` because there are not yet any changes for the current record to save.

Comment: It's slowly dawning on me that BeforeUpdate is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: BeforeUpdate is extremely useful for data validation; for other purposes, maybe not so much.  In your case, consider whether you could  pop up a second form for the user to make her selection instead of having her make the selection from a subform.

Comment: I can see it's usefulness for validation, in fact I've got [another stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006896/no-current-record-error-on-accmdsaverecord-when-beforeupdate-is-cancelled) about using it to validate. I'm just finding it far too quirky.. why does triggering the cancel argument cause an error? What's the best way to handle that error? Why can't I define what it responds to? I'm still a relative outsider to vba, so will probably understand this better after a few more months of working with it.

Comment: `BeforeUpdate Cancel` does not always trigger an error; there is something about the context of your `Cancel` which causes an error.  You might be happier using unbound controls on the main form.  Then the main form values do not get saved until you explicitly save them.

Comment: Context: I have a command button with `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. When clicked I guess this gets delayed from executing until BeforeUpdate event has finished. In BeforeUpdate I have an `If` statement testing IsNull() on a few fields. If there are blank fields the cancel argument is set to true and a message box displayed. When I test this it errors "No Current Record" highlighting `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`. I'm guessing this is because it's still attempting to save the record but `BeforeUpdate Cancel` is telling it not to?

Comment: Can you refactor to only enable the `RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` command button when those field values satisfy your `IsNull` tests?

Comment: I could, I just thought the BeforeUpdate event sounded safer... are there other ways a record could unintentionally get updated by the user without a save button?

Comment: Access will (attempt to) save the "dirty" record when the user 1.) navigates to another record 2.) shifts focus to a subform 3.) closes the form 4.) shuts down Access (which closes the form) 5.) presses `Shift+Enter` or `Ctrl+s` 6.) or selects Records->Save from the ribbon.